# SQL select all products from specified category and all sub-category

Tags: mysql, parent-child, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

items table

```
id    category_id    item_title
1     2              Seagate SSHD
2     3              Seagtate 2.5 inch HDD
3     4              Western Digital 3.5 inch HDD
4     4              Toshiba 3.5 inch HDD
5     5              Generic Used Monitor
6     6              ASUS Monitor
```

categories table

```
id    parent_id    category_title
1     0            Hardware
2     1            Hard Disks
3     2            Laptop Hard Disk
4     2            Desktop Hard Disk
5     1            Monitor
6     5            LCD Monitor
```

Visual:

```
                         -- Laptop Hard Disk
          -- Hard Disks |
 Harware-|               -- Desktop Hard Disk
          -- Monitors    -- LCD Monitor
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM items_table p
JOIN categories_table cp ON p.category_id = cp.id
JOIN categories_table cc ON cp.parent_id = cc.id
WHERE cc.id = "1"
```

Output

```
id    category_id    item_title
1     2              Seagate SSHD
5     5              Generic Used Monitor
```

But,
I am trying to get items from all sub-category too,
i.e; 
1.when parent category is requested must show everything from parent, child and grand-child category
2.when child category is requested must show everything from child and its child(grand-child)

Expectation;
when requested for category 1 (hardware)

```
id    category_id    item_title
1     2              Seagate SSHD
2     3              Seagtate 2.5 inch HDD
3     4              Western Digital 3.5 inch HDD
4     4              Toshiba 3.5 inch HDD
5     5              Generic Used Monitor
6     6              ASUS Monitor
```

when requested for category 2 (hard disks)

```
id    category_id    item_title
1     2              Seagate SSHD
2     3              Seagtate 2.5 inch HDD
3     4              Western Digital 3.5 inch HDD
4     4              Toshiba 3.5 inch HDD
```

How can I modify my query to get all items from category and all of it's sub-sub-category ?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: mysql 5.7.24 and v10.1 MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to warn that `id`-`parentId` method (known as Adjacency List) isn't good for an arbitrary level of nesting. But if you know that it will be 3-tier only, let it be. Otherwise look at alternatives like Nested Sets or Materialized Paths.

The solution is to get all the required category IDs from all 3 levels of categories  and then to apply them to the items table.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE category_id IN (
  SELECT :cat_id AS id
    UNION ALL
  SELECT c2.id FROM categories AS c2 
  WHERE c2.parent_id = :cat_id
    UNION ALL
  SELECT c3.id FROM categories AS c3 
  JOIN categories AS c3p ON c3p.id = c3.parent_id 
  WHERE c3p.parent_id = :cat_id
)
```

See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tCjGASjdJ4UP16dHugMzWi/1

Comment: I appreciate your answer, works good when top level category id is requested (in above data cat_id = 1), all 3-tier category items are shown, however when I try to get child/1st sub-category (in above data cat_id = 2), it shows items from it's childern/2nd subcategory but not from itself . this `1     2              Seagate SSHD` is missing.

Comment: @EsaO I found and fixed error in my query. Please test updated version.  
For example cat_id=2: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tCjGASjdJ4UP16dHugMzWi/3
it shows all 4 HDDs and only them.  
As for cat_id=5: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tCjGASjdJ4UP16dHugMzWi/4 it shows only monitors from cat 5 & 6

Comment: it's Perfect! Flawless. Thank you so much.